# Extending JQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've just managed to extend jquery to include the history functionality via $.fn.extend. This is to allow for the history functionality in JQuery Tabs.

The question I now have is how can I extend jquery tabs directly? At the moment my code is as follows

```
var metab = $('#inv_content').tabs();
$('#inv_content > ul').find('a').history(metab);
```

but what I would like to do is

```
$('#inv_content').tabs().history();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If you're using the latest version of jQuery UI (1.7.2), Tabs already supports this more-or-less. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#Back_button_and_bookmarking

Answer (score 0):

To create jQuery plugin you employ $.fn.extend or $.fn.MyPlugin. To use construction like this:

```
$('#inv_content').tabs().history();
```

you make use of jQuery's chaining feature and for that you only need return selected object at the very end of your plugin like this:

```
return this;
```

to be available for other plugins manipulation.